# populate listbox when dropdownlist changed with jquery in asp mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of categories in a drop-down box in my form. I would like to populate a different select list, based on the selected item of the category drop-down, without post backs and all that.

I created a method in my controller that does the work:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetItemByCategoryId(int category_id)
{
    var itemsobject = DB.items.Where(s => s.category_id == category_id).ToList();
    SelectList item_id = new SelectList(itemsobject, "item_id", "item_name");
    ViewBag.item_id = item_id;
    return Json(itemsobject, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here is my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4">category name</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.category_id, (SelectList)ViewBag.category_id)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="col-md-4" id="mydiv">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And, here is a Javascript function that fires on drop-down list change event and does the ajax call to the action method that returns the JSON result.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#category_id").change(function() {
            c = $(this).val();
            alert(c);
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("GetItemByCategoryId", "Category")",
                data: { "category_id": c },
                cache: false,
                DataType: 'json',
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#mydiv").text(data[0].Text);                  
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("failed");
                }
            });//end ajax            
        });//end change event
    });//end document loading
</script>
```

But, this does not work. I just get a popup failed for my alert.
Can you show me how to achieve this?

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside your `GetItemByCategoryId()` action to see what's causing the failure.

Comment: By the way, your javascript code is not populating a list. It's just showing the first category name in a div.

Comment: GetItemByCategoryId() return the items  and it's never enter the success function

Comment: I know it does. But, something, apparently, goes wrong inside that action. That's why I'm suggesting that you put a breakpoint inside it.

Comment: Do you see that `alert(c)`? Does it show the correct category_id?

Comment: the action return the list data i needed correctly, but the javascript function did not work

Comment: alert(c) show the correct id and also show alert('failed')

Comment: But you get the "falied" alert, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was in the action

```
return Json(itemsobject, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

it must return selectList in the json

```
return Json(item_id, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your javascript code with this. The way you are using the `.ajax()` method is deprecated.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#category_id").change(function() {
            var url = '@Url.Action("GetItemByCategoryId", "Category")';

            $.post(url,
            {
                category_id: $(this).val()
            }).done(function (data) {
                $("#mydiv").text(data[0].Text);                  
            }).fail(function (xhr) {
                var json = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
                alert("Error: " + json.Error);
            });
        });//end change event
    });//end document loading
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your effort, but it also enter the fail function and did not enter the done function!

Comment: What was the error in the alert? The code inside the `.fail` block should show you the error.

Comment: it didnot show alert("Error: " + json.Error), it didn't work
i wrote alert('error') before it and it worked

Comment: Just change the fail block to `.fail (function (e) { console.log(e); }`, and see what object it returns in the console.

Comment: Or you can use a tool like Fiddler to see what error is returned from the server.

Answer (score -1):

**POST**

```
public ActionResult GetItemByCategoryId(int category_id)
{
    **var itemsobject** = DB.items.Where(s => s.category_id == category_id).ToList();
    SelectList item_id = new SelectList(itemsobject, "item_id", "item_name");
    ViewBag.item_id = item_id;
    return Json(itemsobject, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Convert Var in list and that works for me.....

**GET**

```
public ActionResult FillCity(int state)
        {
            using (ASAP_DB_Context DBContext = new ASAP_DB_Context())
            {
                List<city> citiesList = new List<city>();
                var cities = DBContext.Cities.Where(c => c.State_Id == state);
                foreach (var city in cities)
                {
                    citiesList.Add(new city { City_Id = city.City_Id, CityName=city.CityName, State_Id = city.State_Id });
                }
                return Json(citiesList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

        }
```